# How to shorten name of a long list

Tags: bash, shell

Good day,

I was wondering how to shorten a long list of different names, to make it readable.

*List:* (Suppose there are all different)

```
simon, gaurent
simon, gaurent
simon, gaurent
simon, gaurent
simon, gaurent
simon, gaurent
simon, gaurent
```

and, I want to obtain:

```
simon, g.
simon, g.
simon, g.
simon, g.
simon, g.
simon, g.
simon, g.
```

Thanks in advance for any clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '{$2=substr($2,1,1)"."}1' file
simon, g.
simon, g.
simon, g.
simon, g.
simon, g.
simon, g.
simon, g.
```

- Modify the second field to just first character using `substr` function. Append `.` at the end as needed for your output.
- Use `1` to print the line.

Comment: +1 for elegance; note that string positions start with *1* in `awk` (your solution still works, though).

Comment: Thanks @mklement0 Good catch. Fixed. According to the manual `If start is less than one, substr() treats it as if it was one. (POSIX doesn't specify what to do in this case: Brian Kernighan's awk acts this way, and therefore gawk does too.)`, probably thats why it worked. `:)`

Answer (score 4):

If you want a pure `bash` solution:

```
while read firstPlusComma last; do
    echo "$firstPlusComma ${last:0:1}."
done < file
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. This is probably the best possible way of getting it done.

Comment: @JS웃 Thanks; performance-wise, however, I'm sure that your `awk` solution is much faster.

Answer (score 1):

The following `awk` one-liner will print out the first column, followed by the first letter of the second column and a period.

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "} {print $1, substr($2, 1, 1)"."}' input.csv
```

You can redirect it to a file if you want using the standard redirection.

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "} {print $1, substr($2, 1, 1)"."}' input.csv > output.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it in perl:

```
perl -lne 'print $1."\." if(/(.*, .).*/)'
```

[Test](http://ideone.com/VKUm6D)

Comment: You can also suggest `perl -pe 's/ (.).*/ $1./' file`

Answer (score 1):

Using sed and backreferencing

```
sed -r -e "s/^([^,]+), ([a-zA-Z]).*/\1, \2./g" < <file containing list>
```